# DFA that contains 1101 as a substring

Tags: automata, dfa

I have to draw a DFA that accepts set of all strings containing **1101** as a substring in it. I tried one by myself but wanted to make sure if it's correct but can't attach the image as I'm a new user.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your DFA? For example, can you give us its transition table?

Comment: It would've been easy to construct a  transition diagram from a  transition table but the problem is that i can't figure out transition tablr too.. The accepted strings should be like {1101001,0101101,001101001 and so on}

Comment: Show us what you have come up with so far, and elaborate on what is wrong with your current solution.

Comment: @WaqarDanish please check my answer below. Please accept it and upvote if it helps you. Please respond to every reply you receive because behind each answer there is someones time and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an easy DFA. It requires 5 states.

1. state 0 :

   - On receiving 1 move from state 0 to state 1
   - On receiving 0 stay on state 0
2. state 1 :

   - On receiving 1 move from state 1 to state 2
   - On receiving 0 move from state 1 to state 0
3. state 2 :

   - On receiving 0 move from state 2 to state 3
   - On receiving 1 stay on state 2
4. state 3 :

   - On receiving 1 move from state 3 to state 4
   - On receiving 0 move from state 3 to state 0
5. state 4 :

   - On receiving 1 stay on state 4
   - On receiving 0 stay on state 4

So it will look like [image]

Comment: Please check it and tell me.

Comment: Thanks billa.. I myself drew similar one but missed to mention few transitions on some inputs.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. Never forget to add transitions on dfa.once you forget some transitions then it wont be definite.